# Call a function inside a Script Block powershell

Tags: powershell, scriptblock

I have code to register a Tentacle in Octopus and I want to call a Function called RunCommand inside the Scriptblock. It keeps failing when I try to call it inside the Scriptblock. I am reading my data from a csv file but just cant figure out how to call the function inside the Scritblock. Anyone know how this is done. As you can see from the code I am calling the RunCommand function but it keeps failing. I have come acress using the function: call but that does not work either. Please help.

```
function RunCommand{
Param(
  [string]$myCommand,
  [string]$myArgs
  )

$process = Start-Process -FilePath $myCommand -ArgumentList $myArgs -Wait -PassThru
if ($process.ExitCode -eq 0){
    Write-Host "$myCommand successful"
} else {
    Write-Host "$myCommand failed"
}  
return $process.ExitCode
```

function DeployTentacle{

```
#Read data from a csv file
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\adm_qvl6\Documents\RegisterTentacle.csv"

$csv | ForEach-Object {
    $ServerName = $($_.ServerName)
    $WorkerName = $($_.WorkerName)
    $Port = $($_.Port)  
    $Space = $($_.Space)    
    $Pool = $($_.Pool)
    $TentacleSource = $($_.TentacleSource)
    $TentacleDestination = $($_.TentacleDestination)
    $TentacleInstallPath = $($_.TentacleInstallPath)
    $TentacleWorkFolder = $($_.TentacleWorkFolder)
    $APIKey = $($_.APIKey)
    $OctopusURL = $($_.OctopusURL)
    $OctopusThumbprint = $($_.OctopusThumbprint)

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerName -ScriptBlock{

    param($WorkerName, $Port, $Space, $Pool, $TentacleSource, $TentacleDestination, $TentacleInstallPath, $TentacleWorkFolder, $APIKey, $OctopusURL, $OctopusThumbprint)

        $args="create-instance --instance `"$WorkerName`" --config `"$TentacleWorkFolder\Tentacle.config`""
        $rc = RunCommand $TentacleInstallPath $args

        $args="new-certificate --instance `"$WorkerName`" --if-blank"
        $rc = RunCommand $TentacleInstallPath $args

        $args="configure --instance `"$WorkerName`" --reset-trust"
        $rc = RunCommand $TentacleInstallPath $args

        $args="configure --instance `"$WorkerName`" --app `"$TentacleWorkFolder\Applications`" --port `"$Port`" --noListen `"False`""
        $rc = RunCommand $TentacleInstallPath $args

        $args="configure --instance `"$WorkerName`" --trust $OctopusThumbprint"
        $rc = RunCommand $TentacleInstallPath $args

        $args="service --instance `"$WorkerName`" --install --stop --start"
        $rc = RunCommand $TentacleInstallPath $args

        $args="register-worker --space `"$Space`" --instance `"$WorkerName`" --server `"$OctopusURL`" --apiKey=`"$APIKey`" --workerpool=`"$Pool`" --comms-style TentaclePassive --force"
        $rc = RunCommand $TentacleInstallPath $args

        $args="service --instance `"$WorkerName`" --install --stop --start"
        $rc = RunCommand $TentacleInstallPath $args    

    } -ArgumentList $WorkerName, $Port, $Space, $Pool, $TentacleSource, $TentacleDestination, $TentacleInstallPath, $TentacleWorkFolder, $APIKey, $OctopusURL, $OctopusThumbprint
```

}
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `invoke-command` you are creating a session to another host. You don't push your complete script into the session but only the `scriptblock`. So you've got to define your function INSIDE of the `scriptblock` to use it inside it.

```
invoke-command -scriptblock{
    function newfunc{
        #do something
    }
    newfunc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `RunCommand` function at both sites - in your locally running script and remote - you can inject the function into the script before of invoking it [as demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76695304/2883733). Under these conditions, this technique saves having to declare the function for local and remote access twice. However, the prerequisite is that you save the script in a variable in order to then carry out the injection. Like this:

```
[ScriptBlock]$script = {
    param($WorkerName, $Port, $Space, $Pool, $TentacleSource, $TentacleDestination, $TentacleInstallPath, $TentacleWorkFolder, $APIKey, $OctopusURL, $OctopusThumbprint)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple command that works:

```
[ScriptBlock]$SimpleFunction = {
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$Parameter1,
    [String]$Parameter2
)
}

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $SimpleFunction -ArgumentList @("First Parameter",$ParameterVariable)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Function MyFunction{

write-host "Hello World"

}


invoke-command -scriptblock ${function:MyFunction}
```

Comment: you could improve this by including an example of how to pass parameters ( I did not down-vote btw)